# Use of undefined type

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Core;
class State;

int main() {
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

class State {
public:
    State(Core* core) {
        core->setState();
    }
};

class Core {
public:
    Core() {
        State state(this);
    }
    void setState() {
        std::cout << "setting state" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I keep getting the "use of undefined type" error. I thought that if I forward declare both of the classes, it would fix the problem but I can't figure it out. Is it just silly c++ syntax that I'm missing?

Comment: You have `class GameState;` but where is that class actually defined?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `State::State`, you are using `Core` before it is actually defined.  You can fix this easily in your example by moving the constructor implementation out of the class definition:

```
class State{
public:
    State(Core* core);
};

class Core{
   // This stays the same...
};

State::State(Core* core)
{
   core->setState();
}
```

It's much more common in practice to have the implementation of these functions in a separate implementation (`.cpp`) files, in which case the forward declarations would work as you've expected.

In that case:

```
// State.h
class Core;

class State{
public:
    State(Core* core);
};
```

And

```
// Core.h
#include "State.h"
#include <iostream> //This is probably a good reason to further separate
                    //Core.h into Core.h and Core.cpp

class Core{
public:
    Core(){
        State state(this);
    }

    void setState(){
        std::cout << "setting state" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And the implementation file:

```
// State.cpp
#include "State.h"
#include "Core.h"

State::State(Core* core)
{
   core->setState();
}
```

Comment: No, it declares the type, it does not define it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I never would have gotten that on my own.

Answer (score 4):

You can forward declare a type when you only need to name, e.g., to form pointers, references, function value arguments, or return types. If you substantially use it, e.g., in a function definition or by dereferencing a pointer, you need the definition. The way to deal with the problem about is to declare the member function but not to define it in the class definition of `State`. Instead, you'd define it once the definition of `Core` was seen:

```
State::State(Core* core){
    core->setState();
}
```