# Incomplete forward declaration using .inl inline files

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, glm-math

I hope the title is not misleading.

I am making my own Linear Algebra Math library, just for practice and better understanding of math programming. I use the `glm` math library for reference and help. My types for now are:

`class Vector2, Vector3, Vector4`

all classes represent float vectors (later will be `template`d).

Vector2.h

```
#include <SomeGenericMathFunctions.h>

//Forward Declare Vector3
struct Vector3;

struct Vector2
{
public:
    float X, Y;
    //Constructors

    //Constructor in question
    Vector2(const Vector3 & inVec3);

    //Functions
    //Operators
};
#include <Vector2.inl>
```

Vector2.inl

```
//Inline Constructor definitions
.
.
.
//Constructor in question
inline Vector2::Vector2(const Vector3  & inVec3) : X(inVec3.X), Y(inVec3.Y)
{}
//Functions & operators definitions
```

`Vector3` is later defined.This piece of code is giving me `use of undefined type 'Vector3'`. As far as I can understand `glm` is doing the same thing and everything looks fine (`glm` is not including `vec3` anywhere inside `vec2`). [Here](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/IncompleteDeclarations.pdf) is a useful link that helped me understand better what is going on and it looks like it says the same thing, separate declaration/definition etc.

I did an extended search using VS Code Maps on `glm`'s includes and dependencies on `vec2` & `vec3` and I couldn't find anything. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** My main concern is how `glm` is doing what my code is trying to do. I already know the "easy/right" way but I want to understand `glm`' s code.

I am using `c++11`+

Comment: **glm** does not use forward declarations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of undefined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284678/use-of-undefined-type)

Comment: @S.M. Can you elaborate a little more on that? I can't understand how they can use `vec3` inside `vec2` without including or forward declaring something. As for the second comment, I already know how to do that and it's the logical thing to do, but I'm trying to understand `glm`'s way. I can edit my question if I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: Please be more specific, where do you discover vec3 used in vec2. Please refer to the official code.

Comment: I seem got it. You confused with templates. vec2 does not use vec3, but vec<2, ...> uses vec<3, ...>

Comment: Is this relevant to what is going on? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674387/why-can-i-call-function-templates-without-forward-declarations

Comment: No. Two templates are used there. Only one template `vec` in glm is used.

Comment: Alright, I'll dig more into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I searched and understood `glm` uses forward declarations. `type_vec.hpp` which is included in every `type_vecX.hpp` file has declarations and `typedefs` for all vectors (`float`-`bool`,`high`-`low` precision) `line 103`.

What did the trick was the use of `template`s. First of all I `template`d the `structs`

```
template<typename T>
struct Vector2
{
public:
...
};
```

and for the constructor in question the changes were

Declaration:

```
template<typename S>
Vector2(const Vector3<S> & inVec3);
```

Definition

```
template <typename T>
template <typename S>
inline Vector2<T>::Vector2(const Vector3<S> & inVec3) : 
X(static_cast<T>(inVec3.X)), 
Y(static_cast<T>(inVec3.Y))
{}
```